# Convert time_t from localtime zone to UTC

Tags: c++

I have a `time_t` that represents the time in seconds since epoch. Those seconds refer to the local time.

I want to convert them to UTC.

Is there a way to do this in C++?

Comment: Not sure why downved? This question is very specific and clear.

Comment: The same reason as the question should be closed: None :-) You are right, the question is never to broad and nothing is wrong here... Simply forget about the votes in SO.

Comment: A valid `time_t` value (on a Unix-like system) is always relative to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**. How did you get such a value that refers to local time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to show two ways of doing this:

1. Using the C API.
2. Using a modern C++11/14 library based on top of `<chrono>`.

For the purposes of this demo, I'm assuming that the current number of seconds in the local time zone is 1,470,003,841.  My local time zone is America/New_York, and so the results I get reflect that we are currently at -0400 UTC.

**First the C API:**

This API is not type-safe and is very error prone.  I made several mistakes just while coding up this answer, but I was able to quickly detect these mistakes because I was checking the answers against the 2nd technique.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::time_t lt = 1470003841;
    auto local_field = *std::gmtime(&lt);
    local_field.tm_isdst = -1;
    auto utc = std::mktime(&local_field);
    std::cout << utc << '\n'; // 1470018241
    char buf[30];
    std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%F %T %Z\n", &local_field);
    std::cout << buf;
    auto utc_field = *std::gmtime(&utc);
    std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%F %T UTC\n", &utc_field);
    std::cout << buf;
}
```

First I initialize the `time_t`.  Now there is no C API to go from a local `time_t` to a UTC `time_t`.  However you can use `gmtime` to go from a UTC `time_t` to a UTC `tm` (from serial to field type, all in UTC).  So the first step is to *lie* to `gmtime`, telling it you've got a UTC `time_t`.  And then when you get the result back you just pretend you've got a local `tm` instead of a UTC `tm`.  Clear so far?  This is:

```
auto local_field = *std::gmtime(&lt);
```

Now before you go (and I personally messed this part up the first time through) you have to augment this field type to say that you don't know if it is currently daylight saving or not.  This causes subsequent steps to figure that out for you:

```
local_field.tm_isdst = -1;
```

Next you can use `make_time` to convert a local `tm` to a UTC `time_t`:

```
auto utc = std::mktime(&local_field);
```

You can print that out, and for me it is:

```
1470018241
```

which is 4h greater.  The rest of the function is to print out these times in human readable format so that you can debug this stuff.  For me it output:

```
2016-07-31 22:24:01 EDT
2016-08-01 02:24:01 UTC
```

**A modern C++ API:**

There exist no facilities in the std::lib to do this.  However you can use this [free, open source (MIT license) library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) for this.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto zt = make_zoned(current_zone(), local_seconds{1470003841s});
    std::cout << zt.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch() << '\n'; // 1470018241s
    std::cout << zt << '\n';
    std::cout << zt.get_sys_time() << " UTC\n";
}
```

The first step is to create the local time in terms of seconds since the epoch:

```
local_seconds{1470003841s}
```

The next thing to do is to create a `zoned_time` which is a pairing of this  local time and the current time zone:

```
auto zt = make_zoned(current_zone(), local_seconds(1470003841s));
```

Then you can simply print out the UTC number of seconds of this pairing:

```
std::cout << zt.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
```

This output for me:

```
1470018241s
```

(4h later than the input).  To print out this result as I did in the C API:

```
std::cout << zt << '\n';
std::cout << zt.get_sys_time() << " UTC\n";
```

which outputs:

```
2016-07-31 22:24:01 EDT
2016-08-01 02:24:01 UTC
```

In this modern C++ approach, the local time and the UTC time are different types, making it much more likely that I catch accidental mixing of these two concepts at compile time (as opposed to creating run time errors).

### Update for C++20

The second technique will be available in C++20 with the following syntax:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_time zt{current_zone(), local_seconds{1470003841s}};
    std::cout << zt.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch() << '\n'; // 1470018241s
    std::cout << zt << '\n';
    std::cout << zt.get_sys_time() << " UTC\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gmtime:

> Convert time_t to tm as UTC time Uses the value pointed by timer to
>   fill a tm structure with the values that represent the corresponding
>   time, expressed as a UTC time (i.e., the time at the GMT timezone).

(c) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/

Comment: `gmtime` assumes a UTC-based `time_t` value. The OP says he has a local time based `time_t` value -- which I suspect is a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using [Abseil's time library](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/time), one other way to do this is:

```
auto civil_second =
  absl::LocalTimeZone().At(absl::FromTimeT(<your time_t>)).cs;

time_t time_in_utc = absl::ToTimeT(absl::FromCivil(civil_second, absl::UTCTimeZone()));
```

(Maybe there is a simpler set of calls in the library to do this, but I have not explored further. :))

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, you would convert from [time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) to [struct tm](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) and there aren't many examples of converting from *time_t* to *time_t* in a different time zone (UTC in case of the OP's question). I wrote these 2 functions for that exact purpose. They may be useful when you are only in a need ot using *time_t* but in a specific time zone.

```
time_t TimeAsGMT(time_t t)
{
    std::chrono::zoned_time zt{"UTC", std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(t)};   
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(zt.get_sys_time());
}
```

or if you want the current time as UTC in the form of [time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t)

```
time_t CurTimeAsGMT()
{
    std::chrono::zoned_time zt{"UTC", std::chrono::system_clock::now()};    // Get the time in UTC time zone
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(zt.get_sys_time());         // return this time as time_t
}
```

If you run both functions and compare the initial value and the result value, you will see that the difference matches the difference between your current time (at your current time zone) and UTC / GMT time zone.

Comment: This is repeating what's already in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690449/1889329), just without any supporting information.

Comment: @IInspectable - I believe my answer is more practical, being short and providing what the reader may need for such convertion.

Comment: That's a valid opinion, and a justifiable stance. The issue I have with *"try this code"* type of answers is that they don't add value. They are lacking fundamental aspects, such as describing pre-conditions, post-conditions, or exception policies. A visitor copy-pasting this code into their code base does nothing less than adding to technical debt. The value of doing this is negative, regardless of whether this was submitted in good faith.

Comment: @IInspectable - I will edit my answer then,

Comment: That did not improve anything. It explains why you believe this contribution to be useful, but doesn't explain *anything* what those functions do.